# how to get the rxjs to pause a stream then start again later

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I am making something in Angular and Firebase. In the app, I have an RxJs stream of data from Firebase that comes in from a collection so it acts like an array with the async pipe on the template. One item is shown at a time and the other items are off-screen to the right or left. The user can change what is showing on the screen by going through the items one at a time. There is a button that changes the data of the showing item. Because the items are part of a data stream and the data has been updated, it removes it from the stream that item doesn't fit the requirements that remain in this stream because of the change. Is there a way to either pause the stream or in some way keep the data constant even though the Firebase data has changed until all the items are looked at or some other requirement is reached and then start the stream again or allow the updated data to come again?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Angular async pipe and directly attaching it to datastream from the firebase collection then the impact of data updates will be real time as you have seen. That is Infact the way firebase is meant to work.

An easy way to delay the updates would be to save the updates temporarily into a separate variable in the Angular component and batch updates to firebase together at the end. However if another user A updates the data from a different device that affects the stream visible on screen of user B then the update from A will show up realtime.

Another way would be to implement the collection subscription separately and set up a cache (say using RxJs Subject say in a service) and implement UI to use this subject as its source rather than directly connecting to firebase. Then you could use triggers based on the UI button clicks to subscribe when updates are needed and Unsubscribe when not needed. That way the service still has latest data cached but UI won't be updated while the user changes data.